# Make Ranorex wait until text change?

Tags: c#, ranorex

In my current script, Ranorex wait for about 10 minutes(some contingency time, usually only *needs* to wait about 6 minutes but just in case the script is one day running on a slow machine) before moving on to the next action.

In the application that it is testing, the title of the app changes to the word "done" like so:

[image: Application title]

So I was wondering, is the any way of making Ranorex wait until this text changes to done? Possibly making it wait and then check it every 10 or 30 seconds or so, before checking the text again?

My initial idea was to somehow create some User code with a `while` loop which would somehow get the text of this title, but I am not sure how to go about doing this, any help with any ideas?

Comment: Maybe use the `TextChanged` event, then switch a flag to true to tell the Ranorex that it can continue.

Answer (score 3):

Well your initial thought was quite correct.

I would make either an if/else statement or a while loop to handle this.

Basically what you need to do is add the text object that the "Done" is shown in into the repository. (For our example lets say we have 2 states for the text value - "Wait" and "Done")

And to handle the text change I would implement the following userCode method:

```
public void WaitForTextChange()
{
    if (repo.Dom.TextObject.InnerText == "Wait")
    {
        Delay.Duration(30000); // Waits for 30 seconds
        WaitForTextChange();
    } else {
        // Continue with test
        Report.Info("State changed to 'Done'");
    }
}
```

Basically if "else" statement is reached the loop will be escaped.

Also what you can do is add a flag and a counter and fail the test if the counter reaches 20 for example ( This would mean that the test has ran approximately 10 minutes )

Comment: I suggest adding a maximum number of retries since if Done state is never reached, you will have end up in an infinite loop.  Or change this code to use a regular repeat/until loop construct, which is easier to understand for non-programmers...

Comment: If you read the answer fully you can see that it has already been mentioned there.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample of the code construct we use here (to avoid infinite loop) to validate values (sorry its in VB.NET):

```
Dim retries as Integer = 30
Do
    Report.Info(String.Format("Waiting for expected value ({0})", retries))
    retries -= 1
    'Waiting 1 second
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
Loop Until String.Equals(repo.Item.Element.GetAttributeValueText("Text"), "ExpectedValue") OrElse retries > 0

if retries <= 0 Then
    Throw New RanorexException("Expected value not reached!")
Else
    Report.Info("Actual value is as expected.")
End If
```

Replace "Text" attribute (in GetAttributeValueText) with the name of the attibute you need to validate.  Use the Spy to identify the attribute name.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for coding something.

1. Add `text = 'done'` so that the object can only be found if it is 'Done'
2. In the recording module add the action 'Wait for', use 'exists' and select the repository object
3. Set the timeout value to the maximum value (in your example maybe 15 minutes)
   --> If the text changes to "done" it will continue immediately
   --> If the text does not change within the timeout it will continue without
   an error message.

Comment: If the item will not be found in the duration of the timeout an exection WILL be thrown. You either catch it or you have to specify an "ContinueOnFail" parameter for the WaitForExists functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I ment "ExceptionOnFail"

Comment: This solution is good but there may be an issue with the Exist statement if testing web elements. In some applications, they always exist (elements are just hidden when not relevant/applicable).

Answer (score 1):

In my project I have to wait until status changes from one to another and I found this method to be most effective, it does not require code:

1. use spy and find what this "Done" is, create a repository item for it
2. create new action for this item: Wait for (exists and set desired amount of time)
3. modify item's path, add either: and @visible='true' or @text='Done'

In my example, repository item looks like this: //element[@automationid='TextRunRoundStatus' and @text='Playing']

Ranorex will wait until this item exists then will continue.